# Javascript Array empty not empty (Ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

I'm trying to retrieve the address that API google send me into an array. The problem is that I just received
 an array empty(Address) with all my elements. 
I tried to async: false my ajax because of my first impression
was that the asynchronous was the problem but it's done nothing.
If you have any idea it will be good, thanks.

Output :

```
(4) [Array(0), Array(0), Array(0), Array(0)]
    0: Array(0)
        id: 9
        coord: "Rue des Haies 56, 6001 Charleroi, Belgique"
        length: 0
        __proto__: Array(0)
    1: [id: 10, coord: "43 Rue de Boulainvilliers, 75016 Paris, France"]
    2: [id: 11, coord: "Grand Place 22, 7000 Mons, Belgique"]
    3: [id: 12, coord: "28 Place Sébastopol, 59000 Lille, France"]
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

My code:

```
let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ path('url') }}",
    async : false,
    success: function (data) {
        let positions = JSON.parse(data);

        let allAddress = [];
        Array.from(positions).map((position, index) => {
            allAddress[index] = [];
            let latlng = {
                lat: parseFloat(position['latitude']),
                lng: parseFloat(position['longitude'])
            };

            let idPosition = position['id'];
            geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function (results, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    let searchCoords = results[0]['formatted_address'];

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        allAddress[index]['id'] = idPosition;
                        allAddress[index]['coord'] = searchCoords;
                    }, 0);
                } else {
                    console.log("Geocode wasn't successful for the following reason : " + status);
                }
            });
        });
        console.log(allAddress);
    }
});
```

Comment: Because geocoder.geocode us asynchronous, no clue why you have a setTimeout in there.

Comment: I want to populate the array but if the array is asynchronous , I can't do that so I tried to setTimeout each elements that I populate. I don't know if it's enough clear ...

Comment: That setTimeout is not going to do anything with adding it asynchronous. The issue is you are looping ver everything and making all the calls and you are not waiting for all the calls to complete. You need to look into promises with promise all.

Comment: Ok I will read the documentation and try to do this.

Comment: I had two minutes so wrote up what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Promises and Promise all since the geo coder is asynchronous. The following is the success block

```
let positions = JSON.parse(data);
let allAddress = [];
// array to hold promises
const geoPromises = []
Array.from(positions).map((position, index) => {
  allAddress[index] = [];
  let latlng = {
    lat: parseFloat(position['latitude']),
    lng: parseFloat(position['longitude'])
  };

  let idPosition = position['id'];
  // push the promise into our array
  geoPromises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'location': latlng
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        let searchCoords = results[0]['formatted_address'];
        allAddress[index] = {
          id: idPosition,
          coord: searchCoords,
        };
        // resolve the promise
        resolve(results)
      } else {
        console.log("Geocode wasn't successful for the following reason : " + status);
        // reject it 
        reject(status)
      }
    });
  }))
});

// wait for all the promises to complete
Promise.all(geoPromises).then(function(values) {
  // show your addresses
  console.log(allAddress);
}).catch(error => { 
  console.error(error.message)
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I have always the same answer an empty array not empty :(                 
    ``` (4) [Array(0), Array(0), Array(0), Array(0)]
0: Array(0)
id: 9
coord: "Rue des Haies 56, 6001 Charleroi, Belgique"
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
1: [id: 10, coord: "43 Rue de Boulainvilliers, 75016 Paris, France"]
2: [id: 11, coord: "Grand Place 22, 7000 Mons, Belgique"]
3: [id: 12, coord: "28 Place Sébastopol, 59000 Lille, France"]
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0) ```

Comment: I have an array(0) into array and the array(0) isn't empty but the length is null

Comment: I edited the part inside where you are adding the properties

Comment: thanks it's work , you was right . Much to learn I still have :)